# Generating a proto3 file from graphql schema

Tags: graphql, protocol-buffers, proto, proto3

Meanwhile in my world - I have a **graphql** schema from my front-end team and I want to generate some **proto** file from it. There are a lot of `interface A implements B & C {}` and `type Query {F(id: ID!): G}` statements in this graphql schema. Do human beings have some generator **from graphql to proto3**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any inheritance in proto3. The best way is to do it by your own hands.